# Bayes filter derivation

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

I am trying to follow the equations on page 12 of this [document](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Epabbeel/cs287-fa13/slides/bayes-filters.pdf). How do we get from:

$P(x_t | u_{1:t}, z_{1:t})$

to:

$P(z_t | x_t, u_{1:t}, z_{1:t-1}) * P(x_t | u_{1:t}, z_{1:t-1})$?

I was expecting to see:

$P(x_t | u_{1:t}, z_{1:t}) = \cfrac{P(u_{1:t}, z_{1:t} | x_t) * P(x_t)}{P(u_{1:t}, z_{1:t})}$

via Bayes rule.

Comment: There seems to be a multiplicative term denoted by $\eta$.  Normalizing constant?

Comment: Yes, I think we can ignore the multiplicative term which I think is just an adjustment for the denominator in Bayes Rule.

Comment: It looks like an application of $P(A \mid B, C)  = \dfrac{P(B \mid A, C) P(A \mid C)}{P(B \mid C)}$ but ignoring the denominator